# Github Action pattern to prepare a workspace first before running jobs in parallel

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

Say I have (example) three basic jobs:

1. Unit tests
2. Analyze code (lint)
3. Visual tests (Chromatic)

At the very least, all of them:

1. Check out code
2. Setup Node
3. Install node deps
4. Compile TypeScript

Is there any way to run a job that simply executes those four steps before any of the three jobs (unit test, lint, Chromatic) do their thing?

I'm not asking how to keep things DRY -- Those four setup steps are already a composite action, so things are pretty DRY.

I just want those three jobs to block until the workspace is finished prepping. At the moment, all three jobs are running those four prep steps in parallel which imo is a waste.

Uploading/downloading artifacts between jobs is also not viable because the workspace is huge.

Comment: Me too, still finding a solution, my current approach is using `actions/cache@v3` to cache the deps and build output, cache can be shared between jobs/workflow. more details: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows     If anyone has a better solution, please show us.